# 413 Request Entity Too Large only via phantom js

Tags: node.js, rest, iis, post, phantomjs

Sending a POST request with large data set in node js/phantom js results in 413 error. However, using fiddler, if I proxy out the request, it returns data fine when sent in Fiddler or browser.

I have played with maxReceivedMessageSize web.config setting but nothing seems to work with phantom js request.

Do I need any phantom js configuration while setting up the 'page'?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be something to do with user certificates and that uploadReadAheadSize needed to be changed from default of 49KB. Once I figured how to change the setting (its locked and can’t be changed via web.config), now I am getting 200 OK.

A good explanation of the error at: https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7e0d74d3-ca01-4d36-8ac7-6b2ca03fd383.mspx?mfr=true